# How to compare the List values with index values of another list in java 8?

Tags: java, list, indexing

I need to compare two lists (`list1` and `list2`) based on the index of `list1` with the values of `list2` using Java 8. I have tried the below for loop. It is working. But I need something efficiently using Java 8.

```
List<String> list1= new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("A");
list1.add("B");
list1.add("C");
list1.add("D");
list1.add("E");
list1.add("F");

List<Integer> list2= new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2.add(0);
list2.add(5);

  for(int i = 0; i < list1.size();i++)
  {
     for(int j = 0 ; j < list2.size(); j++)
      {
          if(i == list2.get(j)) 
          {
              System.out.println(list1.get(i));
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all you have are indices on list2. I wonder why do you need iterators on both the list. Why not iterate on the indices list2 and perform a `get()` on the list1?

```
list2.stream().filter(i -> i < list1.size()).forEach(i -> System.out.println(list1.get(i)));
```

Comment: Maybe iterate `list2` in sorted order to ensure the elements come out in the currect order.